# How to apply function which returns vector to each numpy array element (and get array with higher dimension)

Tags: python, numpy

Let's write it directly in code

Note: I edited mapper (original example use x -> (x, 2 * x, 3 * x) just for example), to generic blackbox function, which cause the troubles.

```py
import numpy as np

def blackbox_fn(x): #I can't be changed!
    assert np.array(x).shape == (), "I'm a fussy little function!"
    return np.array([x, 2*x, 3*x])

# let's have 2d array
arr2d = np.array(list(range(4)), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 2)

# each element should be mapped to vector
def mapper(x, blackbox_fn):
    # there is some 3rdparty non-trivial function, returning np.array
    # in examples returns np.array((x, 2 * x, 3 * x))
    # but still this 3rdparty function operates only on scalar values
    return vectorized_blackbox_fn(x)
```

So for input 2d array

```py
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

I would like to get 3d array

```py
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I can write naive algorithm using for loop

```py
# result should be 3d array, last dimension is same as mapper result size
arr3d = np.empty(arr2d.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
for y in range(arr2d.shape[1]):
    for x in xrange(arr2d.shape[0]):
        arr3d[x, y] = mapper(arr2d[x, y])
```

But is seems quite slow for large arrays.
I know there is `np.vectorize`, but using

```py
np.vectorize(mapper)(arr2d)
```

not work, because of

```py
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

(seems that vectorize can't change dimension)
Is there some better (numpy idiomatic and faster) solution?

Comment: Actually, `vectorize` will not help you as it is essentially also looping. See the notes in the documentation: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.". Without knowing the "general non-trivial function" it will be probably be hard to help you...

Comment: using the `vectorize` keyword `signature` might work

Comment: `blackbocx_fn` outputs what?  a tuple?

Comment: does `blackbox_fn` always output an `array` of the same `size`?

Comment: You'll probably need some sort of [`np.nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) solution, but I'm not an expert there.

Comment: Added an example for `blackbox_fn` to clarify your problem.  Feel free to reject the edit if it's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.vectorize` with the new signature option can handle this.  It doesn't improve the speed, but makes the dimensional bookkeeping easier.

```
In [159]: def blackbox_fn(x): #I can't be changed!
     ...:     assert np.array(x).shape == (), "I'm a fussy little function!"
     ...:     return np.array([x, 2*x, 3*x])
     ...:
```

The documentation for `signature` is a bit cryptic.  I've worked with it before, so made a good first guess:

```
In [161]: f = np.vectorize(blackbox_fn, signature='()->(n)')
In [162]: f(np.ones((2,2)))
Out[162]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.]]])
```

With your array:

```
In [163]: arr2d = np.array(list(range(4)), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 2)
In [164]: f(arr2d)
Out[164]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]]])
In [165]: _.dtype
Out[165]: dtype('int32')
```

The `dtype` is not preserved, because your `blackbox_fn` doesn't preserve it.  As a default `vectorize` makes a test calculation with the first element, and uses its `dtype` to determine the result's dtype.  It is possible to specify return dtype with the `otypes` parameter.

It can handle arrays other than 2d:

```
In [166]: f(np.arange(3))
Out[166]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
In [167]: f(3)
Out[167]: array([3, 6, 9])
```

With a `signature` `vectorize` is using a Python level iteration. Without a signature it uses `np.frompyfunc`, with a bit better performance.  But as long as `blackbox_fn` has to be called for element of the input, we can't improve the speed by much (at most 2x).

---

`np.frompyfunc` returns a object dtype array:

```
In [168]: fpy = np.frompyfunc(blackbox_fn, 1,1)
In [169]: fpy(1)
Out[169]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [170]: fpy(np.arange(3))
Out[170]: array([array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 4, 6])], dtype=object)
In [171]: np.stack(_)
Out[171]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
In [172]: fpy(arr2d)
Out[172]: 
array([[array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([2, 4, 6]), array([3, 6, 9])]], dtype=object)
```

`stack` can't remove the array nesting in this 2d case:

```
In [173]: np.stack(_)
Out[173]: 
array([[array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([2, 4, 6]), array([3, 6, 9])]], dtype=object)
```

but we can ravel it, and stack.  It needs a `reshape`:

```
In [174]: np.stack(__.ravel())
Out[174]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

---

Speed tests:

```
In [175]: timeit f(np.arange(1000))
14.7 ms ± 322 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [176]: timeit fpy(np.arange(1000))
4.57 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [177]: timeit np.stack(fpy(np.arange(1000).ravel()))
6.71 ms ± 207 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [178]: timeit np.array([blackbox_fn(i) for i in np.arange(1000)])
6.44 ms ± 235 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

Having your function return a list instead of any array might make reassembling the result easier, and maybe even faster

```
def foo(x):
    return [x, 2*x, 3*x]
```

or playing about with the `frompyfunc` parameters;

```
def foo(x):
    return x, 2*x, 3*x   # return a tuple
In [204]: np.stack(np.frompyfunc(foo, 1,3)(arr2d),2)
Out[204]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]]], dtype=object)
```

10x speed up - I'm surprised:

```
In [212]: foo1 = np.frompyfunc(foo, 1,3)
In [213]: timeit np.stack(foo1(np.arange(1000)),1)
428 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic NumPy broadcasting for these kind of "outer products"

```
np.arange(3)[:, None] * np.arange(2)
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 2]])
```

In your case it would be

```
def mapper(x):
    return (np.arange(3)[:, None, None] * x).transpose((1, 2, 0))
```

note the `.transpose()` is only needed if you specifically need the new axis to be at the end.

And it is almost 3x as fast as stacking 3 separate multiplications:

```
def mapper(x):
    return (np.arange(3)[:, None, None] * x).transpose((1, 2, 0))


def mapper2(x):
    return np.stack((x, 2 * x, 3 * x), axis = -1)

a = np.arange(30000).reshape(-1, 30)

%timeit mapper(a)   # 48.2 µs ± 417 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit mapper2(a)  # 137 µs ± 3.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be getting this wrong, but comprehension does the job:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1],
     [2, 3]])


np.array([[[j, j*2, j*3] for j in i] for i in a ])
#[[[0 0 0]
#  [1 2 3]]
#
# [[2 4 6]
#  [3 6 9]]]
```

Comment: I just updated question, because it wasn't clear what is the point of question.