# numpy apply along n-spaces

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4d array, and I would like to apply a function to each 2d slice taken by iterating over the last two dimensions.  Viz, apply f(2d_array) to (x,y,0,0), and f(2d_array) to (x,y,0,1), etc etc.  My function operates on the array in place, so the dimensions would be the same, but a general solution would return an array of shape (x',y',w,z), where w and z are the last two dimensions of the original array.

This could obviously be generalized to mD slices over an nD array.

Is there any built-in functionality that does this thing?

Comment: Did you look through all the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'basic' apply-along-axis model is to iterate on one axis, and pass the other to your function:

```
In [197]: def foo(x):         # return same size
     ...:     return x*2
     ...: np.array([foo(x) for x in np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)])
     ...: 
Out[197]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
In [198]: def foo(x):
     ...:     return x.sum()   # return one less dim
     ...: np.array([foo(x) for x in np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)])
     ...: 
Out[198]: array([ 6, 22, 38])
In [199]: def foo(x):
     ...:     return x.sum(keepdims=True)   # condense the dim
     ...: np.array([foo(x) for x in np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)])
     ...: 
Out[199]: 
array([[ 6],
       [22],
       [38]])
```

Your 4d problem can be massaged to fit this.

```
In [200]: arr_4d = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,2,2)
In [201]: arr_2d = arr_4d.reshape(6,4).T
In [202]: res = np.array([foo(x) for x in arr_2d])
In [203]: res
Out[203]: 
array([[60],
       [66],
       [72],
       [78]])
In [204]: res.reshape(2,2)
Out[204]: 
array([[60, 66],
       [72, 78]])
```

which is the equivalent of doing:

```
In [205]: arr_4d[:,:,0,0].sum()
Out[205]: 60
In [206]: foo(arr_4d[:,:,0,0].ravel())
Out[206]: array([60])
```

`apply_along_axis` requires a function that takes a 1d array, but can be applied thus:

```
In [209]: np.apply_along_axis(foo,0,arr_4d.reshape(6,2,2))
Out[209]: 
array([[[60, 66],
        [72, 78]]])
```

`foo` could reshape its input to 2d, and pass it to a function that takes 2d.  `apply_along_index` uses `np.ndindex` to generate the indices for the iteration axes.

```
In [212]: list(np.ndindex(2,2))
Out[212]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

`np.vectorize` normally works with a function that takes a scalar.  But recent versions have a `signature` parameter, which I believe could be used to work with your case.  It may require transposing the input so it iterates on the first two axes, passing the last two to function.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004266/901925.

None of these approaches offers a speed advantage.

---

Without reshaping or swapping, I can iterate with the help of `ndindex`.

Define a function that expects a 2d input:

```
def foo2(x):
    return x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) # 2d
```

Index iterator for the last 2 dim of `arr_4d`:

```
In [260]: idx = np.ndindex(arr_4d.shape[-2:])
```

Do test calc to determine the shape of the return.  `vectorize` and `apply...` do this sort of test.

```
In [261]: r1 = foo2(arr_4d[:,:,0,0]).shape
In [262]: r1
Out[262]: (2, 1)
```

The result array:

```
In [263]: res = np.zeros(r1+arr_4d.shape[-2:])
In [264]: res.shape
Out[264]: (2, 1, 2, 2)
```

Now iterate:

```
In [265]: for i,j in idx:
     ...:     res[...,i,j] = foo2(arr_4d[...,i,j])
     ...:     
In [266]: res
Out[266]: 
array([[[[ 12.,  15.],
         [ 18.,  21.]]],


       [[[ 48.,  51.],
         [ 54.,  57.]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like [`numpy.apply_over_axes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes) coupled with a `for` loop to iterate other the varying axes.

Comment: `numpy.apply_over_axes` seems to apply a function to one axis at a time.  I am trying to apply a function to multiple axes simultaneously.

Comment: Actually apply_along_axis uses 1-d only functions, but apply_over_axes uses multi axes, short description of the function is: "Apply a function repeatedly over multiple axes".

Answer (score 0):

I rolled my own.  I'd be interested to know if there are any performance differences between this and @hpaulj's method and if there is reason to believe that writing a custom c module would be offer significant improvement.  Of course @hpaulj's method is more general, since this is specific to my needing to just perform an operation on the array in place.

```
def apply_along_space(f, np_array, axes):
    # apply the function f on each subspace given by iterating over the axes listed in axes, e.g. axes=(0,2)
    for slic in itertools.product(*map(lambda ax: range(np_array.shape[ax]) if ax in axes else [slice(None,None,None)], range(len(np_array.shape)))):
        f(np_array[slic])
    return np_array
```